# i have this sql query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

```sql
SELECT k.attribute_title, GROUP_CONCAT(d.attribute_value)
FROM  current_product_attributes AS k INNER JOIN 
      current_product_attribute_values as d
      ON k.attribute_id = d.attribute_id AND k.attribute_uid = d.attribute_uid
WHERE d.product_id='28'
GROUP BY k.attribute_title
```

It works, but I need to convert it to laravel eloquent. I tried this code:

```php
$final=DB::select(`k.attribute_title`, `GROUP_CONCAT(d.attribute_value)`)
   ->from(`current_product_attributes AS k`)
   ->join(`current_product_attribute_values  as d `,function($join){
       $join->on(`k.attribute_id = d.attribute_id AND k.attribute_uid = d.attribute_uid`);
   })

    ->where(`d.product_id=$product_data->id`)
    ->groupBy(`k.attribute_title`)->get();


dd($final);
```

But I have this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, null given

Comment: check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries "Advanced Join Clauses"

Comment: That's not valid PHP syntax. Get rid of `\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by LARAVEL orator which convert the raw queries to schema builder queries but unfortunately its online tool's site is down so try again and then put question